# Keras: Construct a full tensor of the same batch size as a given tensor

Tags: python, keras, tensor

**UPDATE**

sdcbr points out in their answer that `K.ones_like(T)*a` works for generating a similar tensor to the once specified above, the key point being it has the correct `batch_size`. To clarify with another example, another tensor I need looks like

```
C = [ [a1 a2 ... an]
      [a1 a2 ... an]
      ...
      [a1 a2 ... an] ]
```

The case here is that given vector `[a1 a2 ... an]` is concatenated with itself to return a tensor that has the same `batch_size` as `T`.

**Original Question**

I am looking for a way to construct a tensor in Keras which has the same `batch_size` of another tensor `T`. An example would be

```
A = [ [a a ... a a]
      [a a ... a a]
      ...
      [a a ... a a] ]
```

where `a` is repeated `n` times across the second dim and `batch_size(T)` across the first dim.

If `T` has a defined `batch_size`, then the following snippet works just fine

```
A = K.constant(np.array([[a]*n]*T.shape[0]))
```

However, if `T` is a placeholder then `T.shape[0]` is `None`. It would be possible to feed the tensor in as an input, but that seems inelegant and leaves more room for user error.

How would I go about generating a tensor of this form?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing batch_size with tensor first shape, as concepts? Because they are different in nature, a tensor hasn't any batch_size. Can you be more clear?

Comment: Indeed I am probably mixing up the two. I don't quite have a good intuition as to how keras actually handles batching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like `K.ones_like(T)`? Regardless of how you go about it, the shape of `T` and `A` will only be fully specified when you feed something to `T`.

Something like this:

```
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

K.clear_session()
T = K.placeholder((None, 100))
A = K.ones_like(T)*5

with K.get_session() as sess:
    print(A.eval(feed_dict={T: np.random.rand(1, 100)}))
```

produces:

```
[[5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.
  5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.
  5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.
  5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.
  5. 5. 5. 5.]]
```

If you want the rows of `A` to be filled with `[0,1,...n-1]`, with `n` the number of columns of `T`, you can use `tf.multiply` for element-wise multiplication.

```
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

K.clear_session()
T = K.placeholder((None, 100))
A = tf.multiply(K.ones_like(T), K.constant(list(range(T.shape[1]))))

with K.get_session() as sess:
    print(A.eval(feed_dict={T: np.random.rand(1, 100)}))
```

Will give you

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17.
  18. 19. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24. 25. 26. 27. 28. 29. 30. 31. 32. 33. 34. 35.
  36. 37. 38. 39. 40. 41. 42. 43. 44. 45. 46. 47. 48. 49. 50. 51. 52. 53.
  54. 55. 56. 57. 58. 59. 60. 61. 62. 63. 64. 65. 66. 67. 68. 69. 70. 71.
  72. 73. 74. 75. 76. 77. 78. 79. 80. 81. 82. 83. 84. 85. 86. 87. 88. 89.
  90. 91. 92. 93. 94. 95. 96. 97. 98. 99.]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really good start! I need to be able to take it a step further, however, as eventually the rows will need to be `[0 1 2 ... n]`. I'll update the question.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Small addition to the solution above. If using keras you'll need to wrap the tf operations into Lambda layer, otherwise you'll get an error when trying to create the model - something like disconnected graph. So the code will look like this

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

dim1 = ...

T = Input(size=(dim1,))
A = Lambda(lambda x: tf.multiply(tf.ones_like(x,dtype='int32'), tf.constant(list(range(dim1)))))(T)

out=Other_Layers(A,T)
model = Model(inputs=[T],outputs=[out])
```